# Using Invoke-CimMethod to test if a registry path exists

Tags: powershell

I want to convert

```
$path = 'HKLM:SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending'
$results += if (Test-Path $path) { $true }
```

into an Invoke-CIMMethod that I can run when connected to a remote server using a CIMSession.

The below code checks the multi string value of a registry entry.  I am assuming I would use something close to this but I am unsure what method I should use for just testing if the path exists.

```
$Arguments = @{
  hDefKey = [uINT32]2147483650; 
  sSubKeyName = "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager"; 
  sValueName = "PendingFileRenameOperations"
}
Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName 'StdRegProv' -CimSession $CimSession -MethodName 'GetMultiStringValue' -Namespace 'ROOT\CIMv2' -Arguments $Arguments
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could invoke the `EnumKey` method against the key in question and then inspect the `ReturnValue`:

```
$Arguments = @{
  hDefKey = [uint32]2147483650
  sSubKeyName = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\RebootPending"
}
$enumKey = Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName 'StdRegProv' -CimSession $CimSession -MethodName 'EnumKey' -Namespace 'ROOT\CIMv2' -Arguments $Arguments
if($enumKey.ReturnValue -eq 2){
  # key not found
}
```